# Can BoxWhiskerChart show both the median and outliers at the same time?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, options

Is there an easy way to make `BoxWhiskerChart` show both the outliers and the median line? `g1` below shows outliers but not the median line, and `g2` shows the median line but not the outliers.

```
data = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100];
g1 = BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers"]
g2 = BoxWhiskerChart[data]
```

That is, can `BoxWhiskerChart` make a boxplot in the style of `BoxWhiskerPlot`?

```
Needs["StatisticalPlots`"]
data = RandomVariate[StudentTDistribution[5], 100];
BoxWhiskerPlot[data, BoxOutliers -> Automatic]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

If you read the Details & Options section in the documentation for [`BoxWhiskerChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BoxWhiskerChart.html?q=BoxWhiskerChart&lang=en) you will find that there are presets but also the ability to control each element. If you want both outliers and a median marker you could do something like the following.

```
   BoxWhiskerChart[
     RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10]~
      Join~{5}, {{"Outliers", "o"}, {"MedianMarker", Automatic}}]
```

[image]